# Why am I getting an out of range error?

Tags: python

```
i=0
for z in range(players):
    for y in range(0,7):
        hand[i]
        i=i+1
```

IndexError: list index out of range
(in the hand[i] part)
Why ?

Comment: There isn't enough detail here to really analyze it, but one observation is that your inner loop is being executed `nplayers * 7` times.  So `hand` has to be at least that big, and apparently it isn't.

Comment: Your code snippet isn't enough to go on. You don't show us what the count of `hand` is, for example, so we can't know why it's going out of range. However, basic guess is that `hand` has a range of 0-7, yes? But you're iterating through `y`, then doing it again, for every `z`. So you are iterating z * y, and this is the number you're giving to the `hand` range. Probably too big.

Comment: Because `i` is greater than or equal to the length of `hand`.  Python counts starting from zero, but there's currently not enough information in your post to know what you're working with.

Comment: Try printing i and len(hand) just before indexing hand in the for loop. You'll see the problem.

Comment: can you specify what's in hand?

Answer (score 0):

Because there are no element in list "hand" with index "i".

https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.IndexError

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason is that the first time your loop runs, the value of `i` goes from 0 to 6 (note that range generates numbers up to, but not including, the "stop" value).

However, if `players` is greater than 1, then the second time the loop runs, the value of `i` is not reset, so it continues with values from 7 to 13, which I'm guessing you did not expect for `hand[]`